# Is generic type List<byte[]> valid in Java

Tags: java, collections, primitive

In Java, primitive type data can not be added to generic type `List`. However it seems `List<byte[]>` is valid. Can someone explain in detail?

Comment: `byte[]` is not primitive, `byte` is. Byte array is a reference type.

Comment: Arrays are not primitive types. `Object o = new int[1];` (as an example).

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply.